# NameError: name 'Subtract' is not defined

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, attributeerror, nameerror

I'm working on neural network, which I will be using in Dueling DQN algorithm, but I encountered a problem with keras layer Subtract, when I use this layer I am getting this error:

> AttributeError: module 'keras.layers' has no attribute 'Subtract'

Method, where I use Subtract:

```
def DDDQN(self):
    inp=Input(shape=(self.state_size,))
    x=Dense(units=32,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(inp)
    x=Dense(units=16,activation='relu',kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(x)
    value_=Dense(units=1,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(x)
    ac_activation=Dense(units=self.action_size,activation='linear',kernel_initializer='he_uniform')(x)

    avg_ac_activation=Lambda(lambda x: K_back.mean(x,axis=1,keepdims=True))(ac_activation)

    concat_value=Concatenate(axis=-1)([value_,value_])
    concat_avg_ac=Concatenate(axis=-1)([avg_ac_activation,avg_ac_activation])

    for i in range(1,self.action_size-1):
        concat_value=Concatenate(axis=-1)([concat_value,value_])
        concat_avg_ac=Concatenate(axis=-1)([concat_avg_ac,avg_ac_activation])

    ac_activation=Subtract()([ac_activation,concat_avg_ac])

    merged_layers=Add()([concat_value,ac_activation])
    final_model=Model(inputs=inp,outputs=merged_layers)

    final_model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=Adam(lr=self.learning_rate))
    return final_model
```

Other layers like Dense, Lambda or Multiplicate are working correctly, any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Are `ac_activation` and `concat_avg_ac` tensors ?

Comment: A bit of the surrounding code please? For example the initialization of `ac_activation` and `concat_avg_ac`

Comment: @Antry When I use other Merge layer from keras like Multiply, it works fine with them, so they should be valid tensors.

Comment: Have you verified you are using the correct python interpreter 2.7/3.6 ? Have you checked that your libraries are correctly installed to the appropriate interpreter ? Are you missing any potential Imports ? Could you develop on what you have tried/how you have approached your problem ? Also, are you on unix or windows?

Comment: @Antry I work in Anaconda enviroment on Windows. I've checked my Python version, which was 3.5.4, so I upgraded it and that solved my problem. Thank you!

Comment: Okay, going to post it as answer then ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basics first, do you have the appropriate Python Interpreter version installed ?

Try updating to Python3.6 for exemple (if this is relevant to you)